# is there any software of hardware that can mimic an external non virtual camera with a custom video input

Tags: camera, virtual-webcam

Websites can tell if camera selected is real or virtual, I think by checking device instance path   [real vs virtual camera path][1][1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hKr5y.jpg
a real webcam tend to have USB in the path
and virtual tend to have root in the path
is it possible to show the website custom output such as a screen recording or a video stream or ip camera and make it seem like it's a real physical webcam or something like that via a software or an external device that is detected as camera but can I can choose what to output